# How do I configure pm2 to run hexo?

Tags: node.js, pm2, hexo

I've used pm2 in the past for my express apps. I really like it. How do I get it to run `hexo`. Hexo starts with `hexo server` rather than with a js entry point.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running Linux or OSX, you can start it with a bash script.

Create a file called **hexo.sh** with the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
hexo server
```

Then just simply

```
pm2 start hexo.sh
```

Comment: @AbnerChou Well it won't, it's a bash script.

Comment: I have turned it to the batch script. The pm2 task fails.

Comment: @AbnerChou For me, I need to add `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` before `hexo server` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with:

```
pm2 start app.js -- server -s
```

Where app.js is a simple file containing this:

```
require('hexo-cli');
```